# Replace characters following, and within distance to, keyword

Tags: regex, sed

Using *sed*, how can I replace characters following a keyword, but **only** within x characters following the end of said keyword. For example, assume the string:

`foo bar baz quz`

Let us assume that the keyword is `bar` and that character *z* is to be replaced with character *t*, but only within 3 characters of the end of the keyword (not counting whitespaces).

The desired result would be:

`foo bar bat quz`

EDIT: I guess that the usage of *extended regular expressions* may be indicated here, but am uncertain as to how.

`sed -re 's/(::bar) some_regex_magic_here /' infile`

Comment: Something like this? https://regex101.com/r/gY8tS6/1

Comment: @dustmouse Your suggestion suffers from the same issue as outlined in response to user *Joe*: `echo "foo bar bzz quz" | sed -re 's/(bar.{3})z/\1t/'` gives `foo bar bzt quz`, not the desired `foo bar btt quz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
s="foo bar baz quz"

awk -v kw='bar' -v pos=3 'p=index($0, kw){n=p+length(kw)+1; s=substr($0, n, pos);
     gsub(/z/, "t", s); $0=substr($0, 1, n-1) s substr($0, n+pos)} 1' <<< "$s"
```

**Output:**

```
foo bar bat quz
```

**More Testing:**

```
s='foo bar bzz quz'
awk -v kw='bar' -v pos=3 'p=index($0, kw){n=p+length(kw)+1; s=substr($0, n, pos);
     gsub(/z/, "t", s); $0=substr($0, 1, n-1) s substr($0, n+pos)} 1' <<< "$s"
foo bar btt quz
```

Comment: Thank you. However, when applied to multiple lines, your *awk* code omits lines without keyword. For example: `echo -e "foo bar bzz quz\nfoo bzz quz\nfoo bar bzz quz" > tmp  &&  awk -v kw='bar' -v pos=3 'p=index($0, kw){n=p+length(kw)+1; s=substr($0, n, pos); gsub(/z/, "t", s); print substr($0, 1, n-1) s substr($0, n+pos)}' tmp` Can you adapt your code so that such lines are maintained?

Comment: The answer by user *anubhava* works great! Thanks to him for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the following command:

```
sed -E 's/(bar[[:space:]]*(.[[:space:]]*){0,2})z/\1t/'`
```

Example:

```
echo "foo bar baz quz" | sed -E 's/(bar[[:space:]]*(.[[:space:]]*){0,2})z/\1t/'
```

It works by capturing `bar` followed by any amount of whitespace but only up to 2 non whitespace characters then `z` and replace it with capturing group 1 followed by `t`. The `-E` is the extended regex flag for OSX, change it to the extended regex flag for you platform if necessary.

Comment: Thank you. While your code does work on the above example, it fails when the character in question occurs more than once. For example: `echo "foo bar bzz quz" | sed -re 's/(bar (\s*[^\s]){0,3})z/\1t/'`

Comment: sed is no longer your tool then, see the awk answer.